# Unallocated Space after Live Disk Creation

Tags: format

I have a 16gb flash drive that I used as a live USB. While it was live,  it had a total capacity of 2mb after formatting it,  it still says 2mb.  I viewed the disk in disk management and it showed 14gb of unallocated Space.  How can I recover the space.

Ps. There is no option to extend volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this to pretty much reset the device:

1. Go into cmd as admin
2. Enter `diskpart`
3. Now enter `List Disk`
4. It should show you your disks present with its capacity. Think about which capacity suits your drive and make sure it is not the main HD.
5. Type `Select Disk (and the disk no. for your disk. Also shown in disk management)
6. Enter `clean` and exit out of cmd.
7. Take out your USB and put it in again. Goto disk management and you should see your disk with only unallocated space. Right click on it and select new simple volume.
8. Complete the on screen Setup.

*Good luck*

**USE DISKPART AT YOUR OWN RISK!**